# Path to first link the video JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Need a helping hand to help find the path to JSON.
I created this variable in javascript and put a path to the video json:

javascript

```
var urlss = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
    return item.origLink;

});
```

However that this variable myself returning all videos, I would just like the first video.

here is the [JSON](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%27http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml%27%20AND%20itemPath=%22//channel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=) complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to project links from the `item` array if you are only interested in its first element:

```
var url = json.query.results.channel.item[0].origLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

A checked out your [JSON](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%27http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml%27%20AND%20itemPath=%22//channel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=) with a [JSON formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), and it showed that `query.results.channel.item` is an array of JavaScript objects. You get its first item this way: `query.results.channel.item[0]`.